# Module with globals or Class with attributes?

Tags: object-oriented, python, programming-practices, object-oriented-design, class-design

Currently I'm working with a lot of modules where the original developers used `global` variables to control states and to exchange important information between functions, like so:

```
STATE_VAR = 0

def do_something(arg1):
    global STATE_VAR
    if arg1:
        STATE_VAR = 1

def say_hello():
    if STATE_VAR:
        print("Hello!")
```

I have to create new libraries that communicate with these modules and, once I use pylint to check on my code, I get a lot of complaints about using global.

In my head, the structure should be something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    STATE_VAR = 0

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls, arg1):
        if arg1:
            cls.STATE_VAR = 1

    @classmethod
    def say_hello(cls):
        if cls.STATE_VAR:
            print("Hello!")
```

This structure makes pylint happy for not using the global statement, but at the same time, rubs me in the wrong way for the need to use clauses such as `from mymodule import MyClass`, or have to contend with the ugly `mymodule.MyClass.do_something()` type of call.

I wanted to develop my code that is both pythonic and also consistent with what is already in place (I might be overthinking this as well).

I've also stumbled upon this other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919247/python-class-with-staticmethods-vs-module-with-global-variables) that got no definitive answer to it.

So my question is: What is the best practice in this situation. Do I keep writing code that are modules using global variables to define state (keep consistency but let pylint mad) or should I follow the road of classes and OOP (and effectively go against the code already in place)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference between a package-level global (version one for you) and a class variable. They're both implementations of a situation where the state is stored in a single place.

Typically you want to avoid this for many reasons, a few including:

- It's difficult to track who is changing state in the case that these global values are visible to the outside world.
- It's difficult to change code later on if you need to track multiple states at once, like if you moved to a concurrent environment.
- There's no way to get referential transparency - the behaviour of a function depends on when you call it. This makes testing very difficult, because writing solid tests means you have a way to guarantee resetting the state.

I'd recommend using an object approach with instance-level variables instead of global/class-level state:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
       self._state_var = 0

    def do_something(self, arg1):
        if arg1:
            self._state_var = 1

    def say_hello(self):
        if self._state_var:
            print("Hello!")
```

I'd also recommend going against the current practice. The more you add to the pile of bad code, the more places there are for things to go wrong. If you build your code according to good software engineering practices, you're less likely to have issues later on.

And who knows, maybe you writing good code will encourage other people to do the same!

Answer (score 1):

Globals in Python are only global to the module where they belong to, not across different modules. So the scope of `STATE_VAR` in both of your examples is essentially the same!

A class is required when you need (or expect to need) more than one instance of the abstraction formed by the module. If you are sure your program will not need this in the near future, a class likely does not bring you any benefit, you can stay with modules and "module globals" without any significant drawback.

For more details on when or when not to use classes in Python, see also:

- [When should I be using classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072570/when-should-i-be-using-classes-in-python).
- [Classes vs. modules in Python](http://Classes%20vs.%20modules%20in%20Python)